# How do I finish Horizontal space in the line next the heading line?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

A horizontal space is inserted in next line of using \myheading command.(i.e before 1: in the below example). How do I finish this space?[image]

```
\newcommand\myheading\[1]{\par  
  \bigskip  
  \hrule height 1pt  
  \kern 2pt  
  \hbox to \textwidth{\textbf{#1}\hfil}  
  \kern 2pt  
  \hrule height 0.5pt 
  \kern\smallskipamount}  

\myheading{{\bfseries Pseudocode for Alice's Key Generation}}  
1:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\@afterheading\@afterindentfalse` at the end of your `\myheading` command:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myheading[1]{\par  
  \bigskip  
  \hrule height 1pt  
  \kern 2pt  
  \hbox to \textwidth{\textbf{#1}\hfill}  
  \kern 2pt  
  \hrule height 0.5pt
  \kern\smallskipamount
  \@afterheading\@afterindentfalse
}  
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\myheading{Pseudocode for Alice's Key Generation}  
1:
\end{document}
```

[image]